# Select from table join select in Visual FoxPro

Tags: join, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I want to get Users' info with their last dates of login.

```
select * from Users as UU
inner join
(select user_id, max(d_login) from Logins group by user_id) as LL
on UU.user_id = LL.user_id
```

Join doesn't work in VFP. We can't join table to query here?

Comment: "Join doesn't work in VFP" -- not accurate.   JOIN certainly does indeed work in VFP if you use the correct syntax.  An example might be something like:    From Table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.fieldx = table2.fieldn ;   You can do a Google search for:  vfp sql query join

Comment: What version of VFP are you using? It didn't support the INNER keyword until VFP 5, and didn't support derived tables (SELECT in the FROM clause) until VFP 9.

Answer (score 0):

VFP need to use ALLTRIM() in join, otherwise comparing 2 values could result undesirable data. your code should be like this

```
select * from Users as UU
inner join
(select user_id, max(d_login) from Logins group by 
user_id) as LL
on ALLT(UU.user_id) == ALLT(LL.user_id)
```

Comment: if the IDs are numeric, no problem on equality, only if the user_id is character based which is not implied anywhere in original question.

Comment: but it is also not mentioned that used_id is numeric, so there is 50% chance that it it is character type. anyway my objective was not only this question, I just want to mention that in vfp alltrim() is essential in join and compare two characted values.

Comment: Yes, I completely get it. yes on alltrim() and == comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have normalised User_ID as primary key in both tables i.e. Users and Logins and have same Field Type and Field Length. I created the tables users and Logins and tested this query with a sample data and it worked smoothly and gave exact results.

```
select 
     Users.User_id, 
     Users.Cell1, 
     Users.Name, 
     max(d_login) 
         from Logins, users 
             WHERE users.user_id = logins.user_id 
                 GROUP BY 
                   Users.user_id, Users.Cell1, Users.Name, Logins
```